# Getting checked items in listView and putting their tags in listBox

Tags: listview, checkbox, listbox, checked, items

I have this code attached to a button:

```
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.CheckedItems)
            listBox1.Items.Add(item);
```

It takes any checkboxed items in a listView and puts them in a listBox. But I want to use tags instead of names because currently it shows as:

```
{listViewItem}: "item name"
```

I only want the item name and not the prefix so can this be done efficiently?

edit: in C# winform

Answer (score 0):

Ok so real quick I ended up with an answer :) its 4am and i need coffee...

```
            var selectedTags = listView1.CheckedItems
                                         .Cast<ListViewItem>()
                                         .Select(x => x.Tag);
        foreach (var tag in selectedTags)
            listBox1.Items.Add(tag);
```